# Предлог К с дательным падежом

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, падежи

Скажите, пожалуйста, в последней строке стихотворения обязательно перед словом "крестам" ставить предлог К?

Но Бог един, он мир создал,
К нему придём, а не крестам.

Answer (score 2):

Желательно. Валгина пишет:

> Предлоги могут повторяться перед всеми однородными членами, например:
> Смерть рыщет по полям, по рвам, по высям гор... (Кр.).
>
> Возможно опущение одинаковых предлогов, но разные предлоги не могут
> опускаться; ср.: а) Марья Павловна встала, вышла в другую комнату и
> вернулась с листом бумаги, чернильницей и пером (Т.); б) На пароходах,
> в поездах, на автомашинах они проехали огромный путь... (Семушкин).
>
> При распространенных однородных членах предлог обычно повторяется,
> например: Уже год носился по родной стране Павел Корчагин на тачанке,
> на орудийном передке, на серой с отрубленным ухом лошадке (Н. Остр.).
>
> Нельзя опускать предлог, если однородные члены соединены
> повторяющимися союзами, например: Большую еще недостачу испытывали
> колхозы и в машинах, и в тягле, и в инвентаре... (Лаптев).
>
> Не опускается также предлог, если однородные члены соединены двойными
> сопоставительными союзами, например: У Сибири есть много особенностей
> как в природе, так и в людских нравах (Гонч.).
>
> **При наличии противительного союза предлог обычно повторяется,
> например: Не по словам судят, а по делам (посл.).**
>
> При наличии разделительного союза предлог может опускаться или
> повторяться; ср.: а) Не могли увлекаться этим общим движением только
> те, кто не мог уехать по болезни или слабости... (М.-С.); б) Другая
> река бежит по долине или по широкому лугу (Акс.).

http://hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-168.htm
В Вашем примере есть противительный союз, следовательно, предлог повторяем, к тому же без него фраза неблагозвучна.